# What problems could occur if I use two different routers on the same telephone line?

Tags: networking, router

My house appears to have some walls that significantly reduce signal reliability from my ISP connection.

I would like to keep the "main" connection in my den (desktop with multiple printers, etc.) but set up a different router to the same ISP line (different phone socket on same telephone number) so that I can use another desktop and the kids can connect wirelessly to my home network.

1. What are the problems with this idea?
2. Anyone know of a "kindergarten guide" on how to do it? I'm not a techno person but can follow instructions.

Answer (score 4):

The normal solution is to use a "WiFi repeater". Some WiFi routers can [act as a repeater](http://lifehacker.com/5563196/turn-your-old-router-into-a-range+boosting-wi+fi-repeater) (i.e. not connected to the phone line for an ADSL connection)

[image]

Another option is to use [HomePlug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The DSL modems will interfere with one another as they both try to communicate with the ISP's equipment over the same wire.  One might work, or the other, or neither, but not both.

Are you doing this because your wifi doesn't cover your whole house?  If relocating your access point doesn't work, and you can't run an Ethernet cable, then a wireless repeater might work...